# how to use this.$refs in vue 3 composition api?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I use vue3-simple-html2pdf.

```
<vue3-simple-html2pdf ref="vue3SimpleHtml2pdf" :options="pdfOptions" :filename="exportFilename">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>PDF</h1>
    </div>
</vue3-simple-html2pdf>
<button @click="download">Download pdf</button>
```

documentation says to do this when i want to download pdf

```
this.$refs.vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.download()
```

I use composition api and try to do like this

```
const vue3SimpleHtml2pdf = ref(null)

const download = () => {
   vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.download()
}
```

but it doesn't work

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I should refer to the

```
vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.value.download()
```

not to the

```
vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.download()
```

another solution is to call the function on click in the template

```
<button @click="this.$refs.vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.download()">Download pdf</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete to understand how you have built your app. Vue App section is not shown.

**UPDATE**

Here is looks like you are trying to use the download() function from 'null'.

```
const vue3SimpleHtml2pdf = ref(null)

const download = () => {
   vue3SimpleHtml2pdf.download()
}
```

This does not make any sense to me.

It looks like you are mixing `ref()` and `$refs` up. The first is the Special Attribute [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#ref) with access through the Vue App property `$refs` and the second is the [ref() reactivity function](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref). Please check the docs on how to use them.

The [vue3-simple-html2pdf](https://github.com/sango-tech/vue3-simple-html2pdf) plugin has a great explanation page and a [working sandbox app](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-simple-html2pdf-jxy2uz).

If you are not sure how to use the plugin with the Composition API, then I would suggest you to try to make your code work with the Options API using the sample from the Sandbox.

**UPDATE 2**

Please read the Docs on using the Composition API, starting from
[Creating a Vue Application](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html) and especially [Components Basics](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html).

The Vue Tutorial [Step 11. Components](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-11) is also very helpful.

Comment: it works with Options Api. but I want to use Composition API. my problem is that `this.$refs` doesn't work with the Composition API

Comment: Then please show your code.

Comment: I showed everything I have. this is a small template and function `download`. 
in other words, I need to rewrite the method `download` from the sandbox app to Composition API.

Comment: And where is your Vue App instance? :-)